# Publish spring-boot docker image to private registry in CI Gitlab fails without publishRegistry properties

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gitlab

Is it possible to call gradle bootBuildImage and provide credentials to registry without specifying them in the build script?
What I have in gradle script is

```
tasks.named("bootBuildImage") {
    docker {
        publishRegistry {
            username = System.env.REGISTRY_USERNAME
            password = System.env.REGISTRY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
```

I would rather configure everything for the task in gitlab-ci.yml including credentials

My Gitlab job looks like this

```
buildImage:
  stage: build-images
  image: gradle:7.6-jdk11
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - gradle bootBuildImage --imageName $REGISTRY_IMAGE --publishImage
```

When excluding `publishRegistry` from gradle script I get an error:

`Publishing an image requires docker.publishRegistry to be configured`

Documentation does not provide any hints how to pass the credentials to bootBuildImage

I'm referring to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.docker-registry

Comment: It is not possible to pass the registry credentials as command-line parameters, if that's what you're asking. Those values can only be provided in the `build.gradle` file as you've done. What's the reason for not wanting to configure them this way?

Comment: I was trying to remove any configuration out of `build.gradle`. As it stands `publishRegistry` block is there only for the sake of being there, to bind env variables to the properties. If I have those env variables set in the CI pipeline it would be convenient if `bootBuildImage` picked it up. Otherwise I need to have the same block in every single project I'm building